# Grep search order?

Tags: grep

I have two identical folders with files, one on external exfat drive, the other one on local drive. When I `grep -r` folder on external drive it searches files in alphabetical order, yet if I do the same for local folder the search order seems random. Why is this happening and how to use alphabetical order on local drive too?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on file systems. Some file systems may have files "naturally" ordered and some have not (and in some cases ordering could be just a coincidence). Tried with 3 different file system (ext4, tmpfs, and vfat), and creating files named `3`, `1`, `2`  in that order in a new directory yielded 3 different orders from `grep -r .`, none being the "natural" one.

When you use `grep -r` the file name if part of the output anyway so you can always sort the output (and perhaps cut the filename part in a later pipe operation).

Otherwise, AFAIK, `ls` and bash wildcards always yield files sorted according to the locale, so instead of `grep -r` try something like `grep */*`.